# Add year range [1960 -current year] to combo box

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need a combobox where the user can select an year (from 1960 - currentyear). What is the most elegant way to populate the combobox?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say dates is the list and it would be data source for combo box

```
dates.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1960, DateTime.Now.Year - 1960 + 1 ));
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your string round trip? There is also an off-by-one error in your length calculation.

Comment: Event the Convert() is not necessary. This will do: dates.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1960, DateTime.Now.Year - 1959));

Comment: `const int startYear=1960;
dates=Enumerable.Range(startYear, DateTime.Now.Year - 1960 + 1);`

Comment: If you use a const you should use it in the Rango too, otherwise you lose the purpose of the const... And it should be -1 to get to the current year. Like this: const int startYear=1960; dates=Enumerable.Range(startYear, DateTime.Now.Year - startYear - 1);

Comment: @Abbas: *unless you put brackets around startYear-1* Enumerable.Range(startYear, DateTime.Now.Year - startYear - 1) would give -1 enumerations if it were the year 1960 now... the answer given by Haris Hasan is correct as Range requires a count.

Comment: @Haris Hasan: +1 for the +1 :)

Comment: @HiTechMagic: you're right, I was counting years instead of the 'counting the count'... But I'm still correct about the use of the constant! :D

Comment: @Abbas: You are right about constants: no code should ever have "*magic values*", so good advice there :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
for(int i = 1960; i <= DateTime.Now.Year; i++)
{
    combo.Add(i.ToString()) // pseudo
}
```

Comment: Well, I was thinking there would be some alternate declarative way.